# wget to send requests to the list of urls in a text file

Tags: curl, wget

I have a list of urls stored in a text file urls.txt (html pages)

```
http://www.somesite.com/
http://www.somesite.com/
http://www.othersite.com/
```

When I use 
    'wget -i urls.txt'

all the html pages are downloaded.

My requirement:
* I dont want to save the html pages which are downloaded as my list of url is close to 200+
* I want to stress test a server with list of urls

Is there any other option like curl which can serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using

```
wget http://www.example.com -O /dev/null
```